# RegEx Syntax Error - nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone please tell me why this RegEx fails?
http://jsfiddle.net/SrKPG/

```
^(\+[0-9]+ )[1-9]{2,} [0-9]{2,}(\-[0-9]+|)$
```

The funny thing is - when I test it at http://jsregex.com/ it works.
But in my code it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're failing to match is because your second sequence of numbers does not accept zeroes:

> ^([+][0-9]+ )**[1-9]{2,}** [0-9]{2,}(\-[0-9]+|)$
>
> +43 **660** 1234556

Comment: Why was this answer accepted when a previous answer was already telling it ?

Comment: @dystroy, agreed, your answer was first.

Answer (score 3):

It fails because you write it as a string, without escaping the `\`.

You could write

```
var regex = "^(\\+[0-9]+ )[1-9]{2,} [0-9]{2,}(\\-[0-9]+|)$";
```

But, instead of using a string and the RegExp constructor, you should directly use [a regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

```
text.match(/^(\+[0-9]+ )[1-9]{2,} [0-9]{2,}(\-[0-9]+|)$/g);
```

You were also refusing `0` in the middle, which doesn't comply with your test string. It seems that what you want is

```
text.match(/^(\+[0-9]+ )[0-9]{2,} [0-9]{2,}(\-[0-9]+|)$/g);
```

Comment: Well I just tested it at http://jsfiddle.net/SrKPG/2/ but it doesn't return a match - which it should be, or at least it is a match when I use jsregex.com

Comment: @Steve Your regex was also false. I fixed it (for what I guess is what you want). But I agree with tomalak : unless you're really sure of the range of possible phone numbers you need to accept (which is extremely unlikely) a regex doesn't look like a safe approach.

Comment: The last part is optional already because of the empty OR part. But still, even your corrected version does not return a match, and still it does on jsregex.com - why??

Answer (score 3):

Yours

```
    "^(\+[0-9]+ )[1-9]{2,} [0-9]{2,}(\-[0-9]+|)$"
```

Correct

```
    "^(\\+[0-9]+ )[1-9]{2,} [0-9]{2,}(-[0-9]+|)$"
```

The double escaping is a requirement of JavaScript string literals. It has nothing to do with regex.

Upon parsing your program your string literal becomes `"^(+[0-9]+ )[1-9]{2,} [0-9]{2,}(-[0-9]+|)$"` in memory, because `\+` (as opposed to, let's say, `\n`) has no meaning in JS strings.

At this time the regex engine complains about the lone `+` that follows nothing.

Note that the *something-or-nothing* `(something|)` is better written as `(something)?`.

---

Apart from that: Thou shalt not use regex to validate phone numbers.

EDIT: The proof is in the comments. ;)

Comment: just tested this at http://jsfiddle.net/SrKPG/4/ - still no match, but it is a match on jsregex.com.

Comment: Just interested in the last point. Why not validate phone numbers with regex?

Comment: Because there are more valid phone number formats in the world than your regex catches and it's likely that perfectly good ones are rejected by this expression just because you did not know (or think of) them.

Comment: @Steve Here's a better one `"^(\\+[0-9]+ )[1-9][0-9]+ [0-9]{2,}(-[0-9]+)?$"`. The problem was `[0-9]{2,}` does not match `"660"`, but `[1-9][0-9]+` (what you really meant) does.

Comment: @Tomalak Edited your post to improve Though to Thou, a haiku just for you

`Grammar is not hard / However old English is / Check before posting`

Comment: @Cas Thanks for spotting my typos. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak You're welcome, it is a welcome change not to be insulted for trying to help

Comment: I must admit I've thought about that option for a while. ;) But then I also could reply with a haiku of my own: *Leaves fall in silence / you've seen all my typos / refrigerator*